# Cake php multimodel form post parameters

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I'm a cakephp newbie, and I was ordered to use the 1.3 version.
I can't understand (and both guides and api docs don't tell it) how I could create an HABTM association in a POST request.

I'm trying to create a wine, that could be made of many vines. For example I'm creating a "soave" whine, that is made of "garganega" and "chardonnay" vines.

How should the POST params should be?

Given theses **models**

```
class Wine extends AppModel{
    var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Vine' => array(
            'className' => 'Vine',
            'joinTable' => 'wine_vines',
            'foreignKey' => 'wine_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'vine_id',
            'with' => 'WineVine',
        ),
    );
}

class Vine extends AppModel{
    var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Wine' => array(
            'className' => 'Wine',
            'joinTable' => 'wine_vines',
            'foreignKey' => 'vine_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'wine_id',
            'with' => 'WineVine',
        ),
    );        
}

class WineVine extends AppModel{
    var $name = "WineVine";

    public $belongsTo = array("Wine", "Vine");
}
```

I tried a POST like this:

```
Array
(
    [Wine] => Array
        (
            [denomination] => Soave DOP
            [fantasy_name] => 
            [kind] => White
        )

    [Vine] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => garganega
                )
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [name] => chardonnay
                )

        )

)
```

but it does not perform any inserts in vine table, only in wine.
Here's the log:

```
2   INSERT INTO `wines` (`denomination`, `fantasy_name`, `kind`, `modified`, `created`) VALUES ('', '', '', '2013-10-25 17:27:14', '2013-10-25 17:27:14')       1       55
3   SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS insertID     1   1   1
4   SELECT `WineVine`.`vine_id` FROM `wine_vines` AS `WineVine` WHERE `WineVine`.`wine_id` = 2      0   0   1
5   SELECT `Vine`.`id`, `Vine`.`name`, `Vine`.`created`, `Vine`.`modified` FROM `vines` AS `Vine` WHERE 1 = 1       5   5   0
6   SELECT `Wine`.`id`, `Wine`.`denomination`, `Wine`.`fantasy_name`, `Wine`.`kind`, `Wine`.`created`, `Wine`.`modified`, `Wine`.`producer_id`, `WineVine`.`id`, `WineVine`.`wine_id`, `WineVine`.`vine_id`, `WineVine`.`created`, `WineVine`.`modified` FROM `wines` AS `Wine` JOIN `wine_vines` AS `WineVine` ON (`WineVine`.`vine_id` IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) AND `WineVine`.`wine_id` = `Wine`.`id`)
```

Answer (score 0):

after saving the *wine*, try injecting its id into the data array

```
$this->data['Wine']['id'] = $this->Wine->id;
```

and then call an overloaded `Model::saveAssociated()` that will save all *vines* and update the join table by itself.
this overloaded method is described at:
http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/ccadere/2013/04/19/save_habtm_data_in_a_single_simple_format

**edit**: sorry, that's for cake 2.x
i just realized 1.3 has no saveAssociated method

**edit 2**: but it does work in cake 1.3 if you change the last line of the saveAssociated method to

```
return parent::saveAll($data, $options);
```